# passing value from one text box to another in php

Tags: php

I have two text boxes and one button. I want when i will type any value in 1st textbox and click on a button the value which i'll type in 1st text box should be the value of 2nd text box. And i was using this code. Can some one help me on this?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sum']))
{
 $v1=$_POST['abc'];
 if($v1=="vivek")
 {
  echo "welcome Mr.".$v1;
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Unauthorised User Mr. ".$v1;
 }  
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
  <p>Name:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="text" name="abc" value=""/>&nbsp&nbsp
    </br></br>
     Passed Value: <input type="text" name="xyz" value="<?php echo $v1;?>"/>
   </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="sum" value=" Submit "/>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want? Your code is working as expected.

Comment: You want the value in 1st textbox to be the value for the 2nd text box. Why do you test whether the the value is equal to 'Vivek'?

Comment: I assume that you want to write in upper one text box and it will automatically filled in lower one text box.

Comment: I have two textboxes which names are abc and xyz and a button which name is sum. I want to type something on abc(textbox) then click on button and the value of abc should be shown on xyz(textbox).

Comment: @enenen this code is running but there is an error i.e.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: v1 in C:\wamp\www\vivek\submitForm.php on line 22 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0010365304{main}( )..\submitForm.php:0

Comment: @Prem something like that but it should be after click on the button.

Comment: You have a warning (not error) because your `$v1` variable is not defined. So you can check if it is set and then print it, else print nothing: `<input type="text" name="xyz" value="<?php echo $v1? $v1: '';?>"/>`

Comment: in code just change onkeyup() function and use onsubmit() in submit input.

Comment: For the warning just declare your variable (to empty) in the beginning: `$v1 = '';`

Comment: @enenen sorry friend i just tried it but the warning couldn't remove.

Comment: @vivek it's working. Please, be sure that you do this on the first line of your script and above the HTML part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one.

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <p>Name:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="text" name="abc" value=""/>&nbsp&nbsp
    </br></br>
     Passed Value: <input type="text" name="xyz" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['abc'])) { echo $_POST['abc']; } ?>"/>
   </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="sum" value=" Submit "/>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: this is also working but the the same error is coming on page load.

Comment: @vivek, I commented your first post about the warning. It is not an error, just a warning. Just set empty value to your variable in the beginning of the script: `$v1 = '';`

Answer (score 1):

```
  Passed Value: 

        <input type="text" name="xyz" value="<?php 
         if(isset($_POST['abc']))
         echo htmlentities($_POST['abc'],ENT_QUOTES);
    ?>"/>
```

This should do it :)

Comment: Its much better than other codes. But can u tell me what the problem comes in my coding????How can i remove this warning?

Comment: you echoed $v1 in "Passed Value: <input type="text" name="xyz" value="<?php echo $v1;?>"/>" however $v1 isn't defined when $_POST is not set! so you should do if(isset($v1)) echo $v1; to remove warning

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
            function sub() {
                document.getElementById('xyz').value = document.getElementById('abc').value;
            }
        </script>
        <form>
        <label>Amonut</label>
        <input type="text" name="abc" onkeyup="sub();" id="abc" />
        <br /><br />
        <label>Discount</label>
        <input type="text" name="xyz" id="xyz" />
<input type="submit" name="sum" value=" Submit "/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function sub() {
                document.getElementById('xyz').value = document.getElementById('abc').value;
            }
        </script>
        <form onsubmit="sub();">
        <label>Amonut</label>
        <input type="text" name="abc" id="abc" />
        <br /><br />
        <label>Discount</label>
        <input type="text" name="xyz" id="xyz" />
<input type="submit" name="sum" value=" Submit "/>
    </form>
```

I think you want this.

Comment: sorry not need of scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$v1='';
if(isset($_POST['sum']))
{
 if($v1=="vivek")
 {
  echo "welcome Mr.".$v1;
  $v1=$_POST['abc']; 
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Unauthorised User Mr. ".$v1;
 }  
}
```